# Boilerplate code with variable with custom { get; set; }

Tags: c#, getter-setter, boilerplate

I'm having code like this in a User Control. The idea is it works like a normal variable, but when set, it will force the control to redraw.

```
private int _imageHeight;

public int ImageHeight
{
    get { return _imageHeight; }
    set
    {
        _imageHeight = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I understand `{ get; set; }` gives me all the code I just wrote, except the `Invalidate()` part. Is there some way I don't have to write the variable declare and getter/setter code but still get the Invalidate() part?

Comment: Why not call `invalidate` in the same member where the call to the setter is made?

Comment: The goal is to ELIMINATE boilerplate code, not to make more of them lol.

Comment: What does do `invalidate` method ? Maybe you can use reflection for invalidate without write the get set.

Comment: @Oguzhan How do I do that? Invalidate method forces the user control to redraw.

Comment: You could probably use a T4 template to generate the code.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is called aspect oriented programming. 
With aspect oriented Programming you can get rid of the Boilerplate and declare a aspect (as Attribute) that does Invalidate after the setter is called. (Can be done at class level as well).

https://www.postsharp.net/ does allow AOP in c#
I did try it by myself once, Sadly the rest of our team does not think this kind of boilerplate is a problem. So I dropped it again, but it can do exactly what you want.